# Regex to match SINXX11-111111

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

What regex would search for patterns of:

```
(these 3 letters) (any Two letters) (any two numbers)  (a -)  (followed by any 6 numbers)
SIN               XX                11                  -      111111
```

Eg:

```
SINDE19-008765
```

My attempt so far is

```
re.findall(r'SIN^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2}/-/\d{6}')
```

but this isn't returning any matches.

For context, this will sit in the following code to pull matches of this pattern out of a concatenated bank statement row.

```
Bank_Statement['TIDY'] = Bank_Statement['CONCATENATED'].map(lambda x: ','.join(re.findall(r'SIN^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2}/-/\d{6}', x)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^` means start of the string, which you might put in the front of `SIN` Your pattern also contain `/-/` which would match that literally.

Your pattern could look like

```
^SIN[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2}-\d{6}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5LcCb1/1)

Another option to match any 2 letters could be matching a word character except an underscore and digits `[^\W_\d]` using a negated character class.

```
^SIN[^\W_\d]{2}\d{2}-\d{6}
```

Comment: Depending on locale settings, `[^\W_\d]` will match additional characters, such as Latin-1 supplement and other typescripts.

Comment: @iBug That is correct, perhaps as an other option the OP want to match a broad range of any two letters.

Comment: @iBug: this isn't exact, it isn't related to the locale setting. `\w` takes account of locales only when the `re.L` flag or the `(?L)` modifier is used. However, `\w` and other shorthand character classes have to be understood in their unicode acception by default since python3.